# Matlab: Diagonalization of N dimensional array to form diag matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need to form the diagonal matrix from the 3D array:

given `A =rand(2,2,5)`. `B` is a matrix, whose diagonal elements are slices of `A`

`A` has the following slices: a1,a2, a3,a4 and a5, slices 2 x 2.

`B` should look as:

```
[a1 0 0 0 0;
 0 a2 0 0 0;
 0 0 a3 0 0;
 0 0 0 a4 0;
 0 0 0 0 a5]
```

I have implemented it as:

```
lambda=[];

for m=1:N
    l=A(:,:,m);
    lambda = [lambda; l];

end
```

It forms me the matrix as 10 x 2. Where is my mistake?

Comment: If I presume `N=5` this code actually gives an error, not a 10x2 matrix. You probably meant `l=A(:,:,m)` Please be sure to include a [mcve] in posts, i.e. **reproducible**, thus copy-pastable by us, generating the same errors/plots/results you mention. This helps to avoid confusion about your question, such as that it doesn't actually give results as you mention in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built-in function for that: [blkdiag](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html):

```
% random matrice
A = rand(2,2,5)
% split A into 2D matrix (or slice) we preserve the 1st and 2nd dimension
C = num2cell(A,[1 2])
% block diagonalize
B = blkdiag(C{:})
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah the cell are really useful for all the function using `varargin`.